# Relationship between affine plane curves and projective plane curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $\mathbb A^2_{\mathbb K}:=\mathbb K^2$. An **affine plane curve** is a set of the form $$C_f(\mathbb K)=\{(a, b)\in\mathbb A_{\mathbb K}^2: f(a, b)=0\}$$ where $f\in \mathbb K[x, y]$. Analogously a **projective plane curve** is a set of the form:

$$P_f(\mathbb K)=\{(a: b: c)\in \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb K}: f(a, b, c)=0 \}$$
where $\mathbb P_{\mathbb K}^2$ is the 2-dimensional projective plane and $f\in \mathbb K[x, y, z]$ is homogeneous.

It is easy to see that there is a bijection $$\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb K}\simeq \mathbb A_{\mathbb K}^2\sqcup \mathbb P_k^1.$$ Furtheremore, every $f\in \mathbb K[x, y]$ induces an homogeneous polynomial $F\in \mathbb K[x, y, z]$ such that $$F(x, y, 1)=f(x, y).$$
I believe the above data is enough to relate affine plane curves and projective plane curves. Does anyone know how do $C_f(\mathbb K)$ and $P_f(\mathbb K)$ relate?

Thanks.

Comment: The vanishing locus of $f$ in $\mathbb A^2$ (an affine plane curve) sits in $\mathbb P^2$ via the decomposition you described. It's worth pointing out that the affine plane is dense in the projective plane. When you pass to the homogenization $F$, its vanishing locus is the closure of the vanishing locus of $f$. Does that answer your question? In other words, you add in a few points on the $\mathbb P^1$ at infinity that arise as limits of points on the vanishing of $f$.

Comment: Your description does the trick surely? Given a proj. plane curve of the form you suggest, you can set $c = 1$ to obtain an affine plane curve. Note however that this choice was not unique, you could have set $a = 1$ or $b = 1$ to obtain affine models in other patches.
Given an affine plane curve, you can homogenise to form a proj. plane curve. A moment's thought should be enough to see that there is only one way of doing this.

Comment: Did I figured it out rightly: If $\jmath: \mathbb A^2_{\mathbb K}\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb K}$ is the inclusion $\jmath(a, b):=(a: b: 1)$ then it induces a bijection $$\jmath_f: C_f(\mathbb K)\longrightarrow C_{f^h}(\mathbb K)\cap \jmath(\mathbb A^2_{\mathbb K})$$ where $f^h$ is the corresponding homogeneous polynomial and $C_f(\mathbb K)$ and $C_{f^h}(\mathbb K)$ are the corresponding affine and projective curves. So we could say the affine curve is the ``finite'' part of the corresponding projective curve?

Comment: That sounds right.